# It is possible to bind another type inside a custom model binder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a custom databinder for a specific data type and everything is working flawlessly. However I want to know if it is possible to change the binding context and call the BindModel for another type and not that one being bound.

For an example:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var otherTypeObject = BindModel(controllerContext, [other-binding-context]);
        return wizard;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, just create another binding context with your configuration:

```
var otherBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext {
    ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => [object_instance], [object_type]),
    ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,
    PropertyFilter = bindingContext.PropertyFilter,
    ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider
};
```

And then you call the `base.BindModel` using the context above.